# Animation for rotating a view doesn't show up when another view is being animated underneath

Tags: objective-c, core-animation, calayer

*The question has changed, please read the entire post.*

I must be missing something.  I've successfully done this with rotations around the y axis but when I try to do it around the x axis everything gets messed up and I'm not sure why.  The idea is to rotate the layer around an edge (in this case, the bottom edge).  The view will rotate into and out of visibility.  I've searched Stack Exchange, Googled it, read a couple tutorials and read the Apple doc's. My head is telling me this should work but it's just not.  I get the kind of animation I want, but it's rotating around the top edge.  I can get it to rotate around the bottom edge but then it's in the wrong direction.  Here's my code when it rotates in the correct direction, but around the top edge.

Note I have the anchor set:

```
rLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(.5f, 0.0f);
```

Also, the origin of the y is negative size.height when I want the view to disappear.  So the percentRotation will be 1, giving me a rotation of M_PI_2.  When the origin is 0, the percentRotation is also 0, giving me a rotation of 0.  This also allows me to track a drag, which is convenient.

The following code is in a animation block (usually, unless I'm tracking a drag).  Note the cRect is the rect I've set the _toolbar.frame to.

```
    CALayer *rLayer = _toolbar.layer;
    CGFloat zDist = self.view.window.bounds.size.height * 1.5;
    CATransform3D rT = CATransform3DIdentity;
    CGFloat percentRotation = 1.0f - ((cRect.size.height + cRect.origin.y) / cRect.size.height);
    rT.m34 = 1.0f /  -zDist;
    rT = CATransform3DRotate(rT, M_PI_2 * percentRotation, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    rLayer.transform = rT;
```

I've also tried using a -M_PI_2, but the view just disappears without animation.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Ok, I did figure it out, but I'm going to change my question slightly. First, I created a separate project so no other code would interfere with the animations.  I learned that to rotate around the bottom x-axis in iOS, the anchor point need to be {0.5f, 1.0f}.  Annoying that their docs don't mention that, and with Core-anything, it can be tough to know what the coordinate system is on iOS.

It appears that my code was perfectly fine (aside from the anchor), as it was exactly the same as in the stand alone project.  So I started removing other elements off the page.  Turns out, I was hiding another view behind the one I was trying to animate.  It was also animating (no 3D rotation, though, just position).  During the animation, this view was appearing above the view I was trying to rotate.  At the end, the rotating view would just appear above the other one, giving the impression that there was no rotation animation.

The 'easy' fix is to forego animating the hidden view.  But this makes my code a little more complicated when I want to actually show that view.  What I would really like to know is why core-animation is doing this, and what I can do to fix it.